# On Windows VIM external grep command does not support accented characters

Tags: windows, vim, command-line

In VIM on Windows, when working with a UTF-8 encoded file, searching for a word with accented characters does not find the word.

I use a UTF-8 encoded file and write "éçà" within the file. I save the file, then launch an external grep on that string. The file is NOT found.

In VIM, first open the quickfix window to display matches:

```
:copen
```

with the cursor on `éçà` (having saved the file), run

```
:grep "<cWORD>" *
```

should find no match

However, using vimgrep (internal grep), the file is found (but this internal command is painstakingly slow).

Running

```
:vimgrep "<cWORD>" *
```

finds the match.

It must have to do with the character conversion to the command line, but I could not figure it out, even having played with `iconv` command within VIM.

Is there a way to properly configure VIM so it can properly grep files with accents (without going through the internal grep so slow) ?
I have search all over the Net without any clear conclusion.

Comment: Sorry the code got jammed, it should read:  :grep "<cWORD>" * and :vimgrep "<cWORD>" *

Comment: Does it work if you run `grep` with a UTF-8 or Unicode string including accents in the command line? Which version of `grep` you have installed? That information is probably important, from a Windows environment, since there are quite a few ways to run Vim and other Unix tools there...

Comment: Hello, no I can't make it work on the command line either, even with findstr. As of now it seems it works with msys64 so maybe it is the windows command line limiting the accent conversion. I will let you know how it goes, now trying to setup vim to use msys64 as its shell

Answer (score 0):

I ended up writing with a macro the accented search pattern in a temporary file, and then launch grep using the temporary file.

However, I found another solution using "ag" instead of grep, but with a release supporting accents, it works fine from my windows based gvim.

https://github.com/JFLarvoire/the_silver_searcher/releases